# Program to make photo slideshow

Tags: dvd, photos, slideshow

I have been looking for a program for creating photo slideshows. I found this video on YouTube which shows the exact kind of slideshow I want to create:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQsk8RwmGnI

Does anyone know a program that can do this, preferably freeware or open source? Commercial programs are okay as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Google's Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) - it creates great sideshows, montages and movies from photo collections. And it's free.

Comment: and Picasweb integrates with Google+!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Windows Live MovieMaker.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which feature is your favourite part of this video.
If it is the chroma, many photo management softwares could do such processing with a batch, it is contributed by slideshow software.
If it is the splited layout or the transition effects,
[pholody.com](http://www.pholody.com) may be what you expected.

Besides, it has a unique feature that synchronize all transitions with music pace, 
which could make your work quite cool if you have appropriate back ground music